# Error in Clamav

Tags: proxy, clamav, dansguardian

I have a big problem. I ran out of space on the server. After an examination, I found that had a log file of 229 GB Clamav.
I stoped the service and open the file in question had the following content:

```
WARNING: [LibClamAV] mpool_malloc () : Attempt to allocate 8388608 bytes. Please report to http://bugs.clamav.net
```

With that, I had to also Stopar the proxy filter dansguardian, as are packages that go together at installation time.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to solve the error in Clamav?
If I can use the dansguardian without clamav?
If someone had the same error than mine?

Comment: I'd delete the log file and restart clamav... but FIRST, type `tail logfile_name` and look at the last entries to determine if you've got a problem, or just a humungas log file.